# Yii2: How to disable/enable autocommit mode in a transaction?

Tags: yii2

In Yii 1.1 exists in the class CDbConnection the property [autoCommit](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbConnection#autoCommit-detail). In Yii2 is in the class [Connection](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-connection.html) no such property. How should I disable and enable autocommit mode in a transaction? Or should I simply use the following approach:

```
$db->query('SET autocommit=0;');
$transaction = $db->beginTransaction();
try {
    $model->save();
    ...
    $transaction->commit();
} catch(Exception $e) {
    $transaction->rollback();
}
$db->query('SET autocommit=1;');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need for this since `\yii\db\Connection::beginTransaction()` calls [`\yii\db\Transaction::begin()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-transaction.html#begin()-detail) which in turn calls [`PDO::beginTransaction()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php) which:

> Turns off autocommit mode.

In addition [`PDO::commit()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.commit.php):

> Commits a transaction, returning the database connection to autocommit mode until the next call to `PDO::beginTransaction()` starts a new transaction.

Also for [`PDO::rollback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.rollback.php):

> If the database was set to autocommit mode, this function will restore autocommit mode after it has rolled back the transaction.

However, you can set PDO values directly by accessing the `pdo` object [`\yii\db\Connection::$pdo`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-connection.html#$pdo-detail) and using [`PDO::setAttribute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php):

```
$db->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT, false);
```

You can also use [`\yii\db\Connection::$attributes`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-connection.html#$attributes-detail) to set them during initialization of the `Yii::$app->db` object. In your config file:

```
'components' => [
    'db' => [
        'class' => '\yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=demo',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'attributes' => [
            PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT => false
        ]
    ],
],
```